# how to draw plot for the prediction of glm output for iris datasets

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization

I am running glm function on datasets' iris value. Prediction and the regression model works perfectly but I am not able to plot the same.

Here is my code -

```
   #glm
    library(datasets)
    isSetosa=(iris$Species == 'setosa');
     newcol = data.frame(isSetosa)
     traindata1 <- cbind(iris, newcol)
     head(traindata1)

    formula1 <- isSetosa ~ Petal.Length + Sepal.Width 
    #control=glm.control(maxit=50) increases the number of iterations
    glm <- glm(formula1,data = traindata1,family="binomial",control=glm.control(maxit=50))
    summary(glm)
    prob <- predict(glm,testdata,type = 'response')
    round(prob,3)

    plot(  iris$Petal.Length+iris$Sepal.Width,isSetosa)
    with(subset(iris,Species == 'setosa'),points(iris$Sepal.Width,iris$Petal.Length, col = "blue"))

    curve(predict(glm,iris = x,type="resp"),add=TRUE)
```

the problem I am facing with the last line ie curve or I must say I am facing the problem with entire plotting fundamental as I quite a new with this R and its understanding..

I want to know for this particular example or any example -

1. What should be first the plot look like , generall it must be the X
   which is the input as in my case input is (petal.Length +
   Sepal.Width) and y should be the output ie isSetosa . How should be
   my actually data plot look like
2. How should I plot the linear regression output to my data or the prediction.

Currently the plot I am getting looks like-

[image]

I have researched a lot before asking this query and yes I found lot of similar questions but I couldn't get that very properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to manage a line drawn for linear regression

```
plot(  iris$Petal.Length+iris$Sepal.Width,isSetosa)
with(subset(iris,Species == 'setosa'),points(iris$Sepal.Width,iris$Petal.Length, col = "blue"))

lines(testdata$Petal.Length + testdata$Sepal.Width,prob)
```